# Arkham Horror LCG Talent Timing

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

Do you have to spend resources on boosting your skill through talents before you draw the chaos token, or can you see what the token is and then spend resources to boost your skill?

Answer (score 5):

It has to be done before drawing the chaos token. From the rules:

> Before drawing a chaos token for a skill test, the investigator *may* boost his or her skill value.

The rules then say there are two ways to do this; you can commit cards, and/or

> ...the investigator may activate (free trigger) abilities to modify his or her skill for a test.

It would make the game significantly easier if you could selectively boost your skills only when you know you would fail otherwise.